# Airflow tasks are not joining back to the downstream task

Tags: airflow

Im trying to make a DAG on which two (or more) tasks should run at the same time while a downstream task should wait for them to finish before running.

Something similar to this:
[image]

What I was trying to run the following code:

```
dag = DAG(
    'test',
    default_args={"start_date": datetime(2019, 12, 5)},
    schedule_interval=None
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)

end_opr = DummyOperator(task_id='end_opr', dag=dag)

dummy1 =  DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)

dummy2 = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy2', dag=dag)

start >> [dummy1, dummy2] >> end_opr
```

But what I get is a duplicate of the `end_opr` instead of `dummy1` and `dummy2` to join him at the end.

[image]

What Im doing wrong?

My env: composer-1.17.2-airflow-1.10.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is correct! However you are comparing the Graph view (first image) vs the Tree view (second image). The Tree view shows a DAG for each distinct root-to-leaf path. The `end_opr` task is not truly duplicated but rather appears twice because it is part of 2 distinct paths. Check out the Graph view in the UI for this DAG; you should see what you are aiming for there.

Comment: thanks! I need it was the problem...